# PR trigger without rebuilding, testing, redeploying all services in pipeline in a monorepo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My monorepo is structure as such where the subdirectories are either "microservices" or resources:

```
/app
  /admin
  /admin-v2
  /api
  /api-v2
  /client
  /k8s
  /postgres
  /scripts
  azure-pipelines.yaml
  skaffold.yaml
```

I do have one part of the puzzle. I know the following command will tell me which "microservices" have been affected by the commit associated with this PR:

```
$ git diff --name-only $COMMIT_ID | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u
admin-v2
api-v2
client
postgres
```

I know that each stage in my pipeline will correspond to one of these "microservices" and I'd need the preceding command in each stage to see if that stage is in there. If it is, it needs to be run. If not, the stage can be ignored.

My ultimate goal is to have the dev push to remote with their short-lived branch, open a PR to merge into trunk, when the PR is opened it triggers the CI pipeline to build the "microservice", run unit and integration tests, *only* on the "microservices" that are in their PR instead of rebuilding everything, every time.

Would like to do it from one `azure-pipelines.yaml`. The alternative would be to have one in each subdirectory and separate pipelines for each, which could be a hassle.

Suggestions for how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PR trigger without rebuilding, testing, redeploying all services in pipeline in a monorepo

PR trigger is not the same as CI trigger in Azure Repos Git. That because:

> In Azure Repos Git, this functionality is implemented using branch
> policies. To enable pull request validation in Azure Git Repos,
> navigate to the branch policies for the desired branch, and configure
> the [Build validation policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) for that branch. For more information, see
> [Configure branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops).

So, [PR triggers in YAML still not be supported on Azure DevOps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pr-triggers-in-yaml-should-be-supported-on-azure-d/385329), we could not use the condition directly for build, test, deploy like:

```
condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')
```

We have to add powershell task in the build, test, deploy to determine which "microservices" have been affected by the commit associated with the PR, like:

```
$editedFiles = git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only
echo "$($editedFiles.Length) files modified:"
$editedFiles | ForEach-Object {
   echo $_
    Switch -Wildcard ($_ ) {
        'app/admin-v2/*' { 
              # If the admin-v2 is updated, we need to generate the variable Enable_Admin-v2
              Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Enable_Admin-v2]True" 
         }        
        'app/api-v2/*' { Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=api-v2]True"  }
        # The rest of your path filters
    }
}
```

This script sets variables which are then referenced in custom conditions in the next  step in the build, test, deploy pipeline:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Enable_Admin-v2'], 'True'))
```